# force a div to always stay to the right of another element?

Tags: html, css, css-float

In the example below, I have two divs floated next to each other which works correctly when the contents of the div on the right is smaller then then the available width. Once it's larger the div gets placed below the left div.

How do I ensure the right div remains in place and just hides the overflow text?

---

```
<div class="parent" width="50px>
    <div class="left">
        Name:
        </br>
        Age:
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Nero Oliver Paul Quincy Randolph Sherman Thomas Uncas Victor
        </br>
        19
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.parent {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

.right {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Your width attribute is missing its closing quote but, more importantly, a div doesn't have a width attribute. Use CSS.

Comment: Also, assuming you want name and age to line up with their corresponding values you would be much better off working with them in pairs, not collecting all keys, and then all corresponding values, in separate elements. This will also be more maintainable. (If you had 10 keys they would be widely separated from their values in the HTML.) Or use a table.

Comment: @AndyG Thank you, I simplified the code to make it as easy as possible to solve the actual CSS issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of floats and set `white-space: nowrap` on parent

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" width="50px">
  <div class=" left ">
    Name:
    <br> Age:
  </div>
  <div class="right ">
    Nero Oliver Paul Quincy Randolph Sherman Thomas Uncas Victor
    <br> 19
  </div>
</div>
```